# Required attribute triggers exception when attribute nullable

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I've been writing some tests and it turns up that the `dbContext.SaveChanges()` raises the exception if `[Required]` is over a nullable property which the value has not been assigned:

```
class Object1 {

    public int Object1ID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Some required data has not been set.")]
    public int? SomeRequiredData { get; set; }
}

using(CustomDbContext dbContext = new CustomDbContext()) {
    Object1 obj = new Object1();
    dbContext.Objects1.Add(obj);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

The code above will throw: `System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException`.  Why isn't this occurring for normal (i.e. not nullable) properties?

Comment: It will throw if the data is invalid, i.e. the property is null. It will never throw this exception with required on a property with a non nullable type as the property will always have a value (in the case of int it will be 0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because non nullable property can't be null and thus have a default value.

So the property is always set, at least to his default value, so the required constraint is always respected.

Comment: So you are telling me that if I don't assign the value to a variable it still has a (default) value?

Comment: a variable like int, datetime, bool... yes, absolutely.